# PowerApps form FILTER by ID

Tags: variables, filter, powerapps

I have a PowerApps FORM that I need filtered by the underlying list column which is ID and its known type is NUMBER or INT. I've added into the ITEM property, something a kin to FILTER(SOURCETABLENAME, SOURCETABLEMANE.ID = varNumber). Even when I hard code the varNumber to a 1, which does exist because I've used FIRST to see what the ID is, the FILTER fails.

TIA
John

I want to basically FILTER the form by a VARIABLE I've set elsewhere. I've used the SET and checked it against a LABEL. Any suggestions and ideas please?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is NOT a GALLERY.  Its a FORM bound to a SharePoint LIST.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the that **Datasource** in your form is SOURCETABLENAME, the **Item** property needs to be of type record and you can use the LookUp function for that

```
LookUp(Table*, Formula [, *ReductionFormula* ] )
```

- Table - Required. Table to search. In the UI, the syntax is shown as source above the function box.
- Formula - Required. The formula by which each record of the table is
  evaluated. The function returns the first record that results in
  true. You can reference columns within the table. In the UI, the
  syntax is shown as condition above the function box.
- ReductionFormula - Optional. This formula is evaluated over the
  record that was found, and then reduces the record to a single value.
  You can reference columns within the table. If you don't use this
  parameter, the function returns the full record from the table. In
  the UI, the syntax is shown as result above the function box.

Your formula should look like

```
LookUp(SOURCETABLENAME, ID = varNumber)
```